# Upgrade my version code of the app for play store

Tags: flutter

I published my app on the play store several times before, and according to another question on stackoverflow that I followed I made my code version 1.1.0+2 in the pubspec.yaml file
now I had a major change in the app and I want the version to be 2.0.0 but I don't understand the last part of the code version (+2), what should it be now and do I have to put it in the version code or just update it to 2.0.0 in the pubspec.yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.1.0 is called version name. it is just a string separated by period(.)
+
2 is build number which need to be incremented each time when you create build.

In Play Store, version name does not matter, only build number needs to be unique every time. if you upload a build using 1.1.0+2 than you are allowed to keep the version name same, if each time you have unique build number.
Explore more at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning

In App Store, for each version name you can have every build number. if your version name is 1.0.0 than you can have build no from 1 to n and again when you update your version name to 2.0.0 than you are allowed to have build no from 1 to n.
Explore more at
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2420/_index.html

Comment: thanks so much! so what I understood from you is that (+2) is the build number which I can use if I'm not going to change my version name but if I'm changing the version name from 1.1.0 to 2.0.0 I don't have to use the build number this time, is that right?

Comment: No, build number is something which defines uniqueness of build so each time when you upload build it need to have new build number.

Comment: In Playstore build number is independent from version name so if you only update build number than also it will allow you to upload but in case of Appstore version name and build number both are connected, so for each version name it can have 1 to n build number.